# Dynamic Textboxes spacing issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create dynamic textboxes in a winforms application.  It creates correctly by does not space it correctly.  What am I doing wrong here.

```
private void createTextBoxes()
{

  int width = 69;
  int height = 20;
  int spacing = 32;
  TextBox[] subAmt = new TextBox[12];
  for (int i = 0; i <= 11; ++i)
  {
      subAmt[i] = new TextBox();
      subAmt[i].Size = new Size(width, height);
      subAmt[i].Margin = new Padding(3);
      subAmt[i].Location = new Point(279, (i * height) + spacing); // <-- this is should space it out but does not
      subAmt[i].KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtAmt_KeyPress);

       plSubscription.Controls.Add(subAmt[i]);

   }
}
```

I have the similar code for combobox it seem to space correctly

```
private void createCombo()
{

  int width = 79;
  int height = 24;
  int spacing = 28;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 11; ++i)
  {
      ComboBox newBox = new ComboBox();
      newBox.Name = "SubYears";
      newBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
      newBox.Size = new Size(width, height);
      newBox.Location = new Point(145, (i * height) + spacing);

      plSubscription.Controls.Add(newBox);
      fillComboData(newBox);
   }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the comboboxes and textboxes

[image]

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, kindly attach ta screenshot of what you want.

Comment: not sure if I can attach a screenshot but the issue is there is no spacing in between each textbox

Comment: So you want every `textbox` in front of a combo box? If you can't attach a screenshot, then explain in easy words what ever you want..

Comment: See my screenshot I just want the spacing like the comboboxes

Comment: When you do this sort of thing. Think of it as an 2D array of cells, then position each component (based on horizontal and vertical alignments) within the cell. i.e. all cells in a row have the same top and height, all cells in a column have the same width and left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced your `createTextBoxes()` these values:

```
int width = 69;
int height = 20;
int spacing = 32;
```

with your `createCombo()` values:

```
int width = 79;
int height = 24;
int spacing = 28;
```

and i got the following result.

[image]

Comment: Strange I did that earlier it did not work, now it does.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it works. what's the problem?

---

You cant change textbox height in singleline mode, and in your code, you set it lower than actual height.

---

Use this:

```
        int width = 69;
        int height = 10;
        int spacing = 0;
        TextBox[] subAmt = new TextBox[12];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; ++i)
        {
            subAmt[i] = new TextBox();
            subAmt[i].Size = new Size(width, height);
        // mycode
            height = subAmt[i].Height;
        // ***
            subAmt[i].Margin = new Padding(3);
            subAmt[i].Location = new Point(279, (i * height) + spacing); // <-- this is should space it out but does not

            this.Controls.Add(subAmt[i]);
        }
```

Comment: See my reply to @shaharyar

Comment: not sure if I understood you but will try.  I even added Padding